# How to assign a Makefile variable from the output of a shell command

Tags: variables, makefile, target, assign, recipe

I am trying to extract a string from a file and assign it to a variable. I have a file called tool_vaersions.env and it contains the following:

```
armcc install_dir /tools/compiler/armcc
gcc   intall_dir /tools/compiler/gcc
```

The Makefile has the following:

```
TOOL1 := gcc
TOOL2 := armcc

TOOL_VER1 := $(shell "grep -i $(TOOL1)  tool_versions.env" )

TOOL_INFO:
    $(eval TOOL_VER2=$(shell "grep -i $(TOOL2)  tool_versions.env" ))
    @(echo TOOL_VER1 is $(TOOL_VER1))
    @(echo TOOL_VER2 is $(TOOL_VER2))
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here but the echo of TOOL_VER1 and TOOL_VER2 returns nothing. I wanted both these variables to only have the path /tools/compiler/gcc and /tools/compiler/armcc but I cant seem to get this work before I introduce strip and string manipulation.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Try removing the quotes.

Comment: Delete the `eval`.  You shouldn't use eval until you're a makefile guru, and you shouldn't use it in a recipe hardly ever.  Delete the extra parens around `(echo ...)` and just write `echo ...`; those parens are not needed.  I'm sure @HolyBlackCat is right but to be sure, you should be including the error messages you get when you run make... if that's the real problem you will _definitely_ see an error like **/bin/sh: 1: grep -i ...**  When asking for help on SO you should always cut and paste error messages (verbatim).

Comment: Thanks this worked but is there a ways to call a target and make the variable available after the target has been executed - in this case TOOL_VER2

Comment: Short answer: no, Make doesn't work that way. Longer answer: yes, but it's a pain, and you should probably rethink your design.

Comment: .ONESHELL allows for setting shell variables for the duration of the recipe. You'd do something like `TOOL_VER2=\`grep...\`` on the first line and then `$$TOOL_VER2` to expand it.